# I am trying to Navigate to a different screen automatically after my Fetch call using useEffect() but getting an object is undefined error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, use-effect, use-state

Right now I am able to make the call every 3 seconds and start getting the data and I have a button which after pressing, i can move to the final screen and render the data but when i try to do this, automatically I get undefined error.

I have tried many ways to put my navigation code after the first `.then()` and inside of `.then()` but cant seem to navigate automatically once the data comes from the `fetch` call.

I want to get rid of the button and automatically navigate to the next screen with the data i am pulling from the last screen every 3 seconds any help would be highly appreciated!!

Thank you all

```
const ExpressStore = props => {

    const [charector, setCharectorObject] = useState({status:'hello', message: '', user: {orders: []}});
    useEffect( () => {
        const interval = setInterval( () => getInfo().then( data => setCharectorObject(data) ), 3000);
       
        return () => {
            clearInterval(interval)
        }
        
    },[]);

async function getInfo() {
    const response = await fetch('server Call url',{
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${access_token}`
        }
    })
    const data = await response.json()
    //console.log(data)
    return data;


function onNextScreenClick(localChar) {
        Navigation.push(props.componentId, {
            component: {
                name: 'FinalScreen',
                options: {
                    topBar: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'FinalScreen'
                        }
                    }
                },
                passProps: {
                    hello: localChar
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: what you try to do? i understand u doing api call every 3 seconds. can you tell the scenario?

Comment: So I am making the call every 3 seconds and it returns me an obj which I store in my state. Then i have a button which when clicked navigates to the next page and renders that data from my state there. I am trying to navigate to the other screen automatically without having to press the button. so basically once i get the data i want to automatically move on to the next screen after few seconds

Comment: so basically I am calling the api every 3 seconds and once it returns me data, I want to navigate to the finalScreen and show the data there without having to use the button.